# Derivative of the osmotic pressure with respect to the chemical potential via Gibbs-Duhem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential

So I was reading through Atkins "Physical chemistry" 10th edition and was wondering something. Suppose you have an athermal system of $k$ particles, let us define the Gibbs-Duhem equation for this system as:

$$\text{d}P=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i \text{d}\mu_i,$$

where all $n_i's$ are coupled through some relation $f(n_i,n_{i+1},n_{i+2},...)=0$. Suppose you are interested in the following quantity:

$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial\mu_1}\right)_\text{T}$$

Sometimes you see this defined as "Divide both sides by $\text{d}\mu_1$" to obtain

$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial\mu_i}\right)_\text{T}=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i \left(\frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial \mu_1}\right)_\text{T}.$$

This doesn't really makes sense to me, as through the chain rule one would expect a combination of derivatives of $n_i$ with respect to $\mu_1$ and $\mu_i$ with respect to $\mu_1$. Could anyone please explain what is happening here.

Comment: I guess that Atkin's definition should be "Divide both sides by d$\mu_1$" to obtain $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial\mu_1}\right)_\text{T}=...$". Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes sorry, type-o. I've editted this in the question.

Comment: It has to do with definitions of *differential* and *derivative*. See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565329/247642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that you might not be familiar with the concept of the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). It basically is the chain rule already. Let me make an example: Imagine you have a function $f(x,y)$. Right now $x,y$ are just some coordinates. But you could consider a specific trajectory described by $x(t),y(t)$ where $t$ is time and both coordinates are some function of time. If you now want to compute the time derivative of $f(x(t),y(t))$, you use the chain rule: $$ \frac{d}{dt}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$
This can also be seen by taking the product of the row vector $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ and the column vector $\left(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^T$. This is useful because it separates the object that depends on the chosen function f (which is th row vector) from the object that depends on the explicit trajectory (the column vector). In "differential geometry notation" this row vector gets written basically as $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$ where $dx,dy$ can be seen as something like the basis row vectors $(1,0),(0,1)$. Please don't take this as a mathematically rigorous explanation. If you are looking for one, read a book about differential geometry (or maybe just about conventional multidimensional calculus). My answer is more about providing the heuristics to understand what the notation means.

So your $dP$ can be understood as the corresponding row vector which you have to multiply with the column vector $\left(\frac{\partial\mu_1}{\partial\lambda},...,\frac{\partial\mu_k}{\partial\lambda}\right)^T$ (where there are now partial derivatives because the things depend on more than just one variable) if you want to compute $\frac{\partial P}{\partial \lambda}$. So actually we can compare the $dP$ given with the general formula to get $n_i=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \mu_i}\right)_{\mu_j,j\ne i}$ (where I mean that the partial derivative is taken while every other $\mu$ is constant). So why do we even need to write down an expression here for $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \mu_i}\right)_T$ if it is just $n_1$? Well, it isn't. Now $T$ is constant, not all other $\mu$. This means we have a different "trajectory" parametrized by the same parameter ($\mu_1$) like one could also have different trajectories $x'(t),y'(t)$ which are also parametrized by time.

If you plug what we just found for the $n_i$ in you can directly see that the chain rule has been applied correctly in $$ \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \mu_1}\right)_T=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i \left( \frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial \mu_1}\right)_T=\sum_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \mu_i}\right)_{\mu_j,j\ne i} \left( \frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial \mu_1}\right)_T$$

Comment: Great answer, it makes complete sense now. Especially through the fact that you separate the trajectory-dependent terms. Thank you.