# Doubt in notations for thermodynamic quantities

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

In my book, the first law of thermodynamics is written as:
$$\delta Q=dU+\delta W$$

Now it's strictly written why we have different notations for heat and work and internal energy. It's written that internal energy is a perfect differential while work and heat are not because $U$ is a function of the system's state, which I can grasp. If anyone can help me understand this better, it would be good.

Comment: There are many duplicates to this question: check https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701026/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use different differential notation for heat and work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701026/)