# Why is the force being the differential of a potential equivalent to it being a conservative force?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

I was reading Goldstein's book on mechanics and came across this theorem:

$F(r) = - \nabla V(r)$ is a necessary and sufficient condition of the force field being conservative.

So far, I have understood the condition of a force being conservative as path independence: $\int_{\text{closed loop}} F \cdot ds = 0$.

The new condition was justified by a brief argument which I don't follow:

> The existence of V can be inferred intuitively by a simple argument. If $W_{12}$ is independent of the path of integration between the end points 1 and 2, it should be possible to express $W_{12}$ as the change in quantity that depends only upon the positions of the end points.

I follow that for the work done must depend only upon the end points $W = W(start, end)$ and to ensure the path integral is always zero the "return trip" must cancel out the "outgoing trip", i.e., $W = W(start, end) = -W(end, start)$. But how do I go from this to the form given above?

Comment: Since any scalar $V$ gives $\nabla \times \nabla V = 0$, you can use stoke's theorem to show $\int_{C}{\nabla V \cdot d\vec{r}}=\int_{A}{(\nabla \times \nabla V) \cdot d\vec{s}}=0$ where $A$ is the area enclosed by the loop $C$.

Comment: @AndyChen Thanks, I can now see why the $F = - \nabla V$ implies $\int_c F \cdot ds = 0$ but I can't see why the reverse is true... Is the reverse true?

Comment: Yes, the reverse is true. We can define some scalar $V$ and show $F=-\nabla V$: Set some point $x_0$ and without loss of generality , we make $V(x_0)=0$. For any point $x$, we define $V(x)=-\int_{L}{F \cdot ds}$ where $L$ is the straight line starting from $x_0$ and stopping at $x$.  You can show $F=-\nabla V$ by definition with the condition that $\int_{c}{F \cdot ds}=0$ where $c$ is a closed and non-intersecting curve. Also, sorry for the notation difference in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

If a force can be represented as
$$\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U(\mathbf{r}),
$$
we can calculate the work over a closed circuit as
$$
\oint\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=-\oint\nabla U(\mathbf{r}) \cdot d\mathbf{r}=
-\oint dU(\mathbf{r})=0,
$$
since $U(\mathbf{r})$ is a uniquely valued function.
Note that I used here the full differential ([see here for more background](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565329/247642)):
$$
dU(\mathbf{r})=\nabla U(\mathbf{r}) \cdot d\mathbf{r}=
\frac{\partial_xU(x,y,z)}{\partial x}dx +
\frac{\partial_xU(x,y,z)}{\partial y}dy +
\frac{\partial_xU(x,y,z)}{\partial z}dz
$$

Another amusing (although non-canonical way) to use this is by looking at the [first integral](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/First_integral) of the Newton's second law:
$$
m\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=-\nabla U(\mathbf{r}),
$$
multiply it by $\dot{\mathbf{r}}$ and perform some algebraic transformations, we obtain:
$$
0=\left[m\ddot{\mathbf{r}} +\nabla U(\mathbf{r})\right]\dot{\mathbf{r}}=
m\ddot{\mathbf{r}}\dot{\mathbf{r}} +\nabla U(\mathbf{r})\dot{\mathbf{r}}=
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{m\dot{\mathbf{r}}^2}{2}+U(\mathbf{r})\right]=\frac{d}{dt}E(t)
$$
That is, the quantity $E(t)=\frac{m\dot{\mathbf{r}}^2}{2}+U(\mathbf{r})$ does not change with time (i.e., conserved) along the trajectories described by the equation of motion. This is just a mathematical fact - there is no much flexibility in adjusting it.