# Converting differential to gradient

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, calculus

Landau & Lifschitz's fluid mechanics book proposes the following statement for an isentropic proccess:

$$dH=vdp \Rightarrow \nabla H=v\nabla p$$

What's the rigorous way to get this result (converting differentials to gradients)?

Comment: Relevant: [differential vs. derivative](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565329/247642). In a nutshell: $df=\nabla f\cdot \mathbf{dx}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Cartan differential basically encodes the gradient by:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm d H
&=\partial_1H\mathrm dx_1
+\partial_2H\mathrm dx_2
+\partial_3H\mathrm dx_3 \\
=v\mathrm d p
&=v(\partial_1p\mathrm dx_1
+\partial_2p\mathrm dx_2
+\partial_3p\mathrm dx_3).
\end{align*}
By applying this to $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ as well as using $\mathrm dx_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$, we get $\partial_iH=v\partial_ip$ and therefore $\nabla H=v\nabla p$.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship $dH = v dp$ is valid along any reversible path. Suppose that path is a function of space, e.g., $x=x(t)$. Along each step $dx$ of the path the above equation is satisfied, then dividing by $dx$ we obtain $$\frac{dH}{dx} = v \frac{dp}{dx}$$ The isentropic process is reversible, so the above holds.