# Confusion regarding the definition of electrochemical potential

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential, electrochemistry

I am having trouble understanding the concept of the electrochemical potential $\mu$. In my textbook the electrochemical potential is defined as $\mu=\frac{\partial G}{\partial n}$. It seems to me as an arbitrary equation that I cannot understand which simply defines the partial derivative of $G$ as "electrochemical potential". I know that this is obviously false but I am searching for an intuitive explanation of the equation above. I am also interested in the uses that this quantity has other than the prediction of a concentration equilibrium. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Very loosely it is the change in (free) energy of the system when you add one additional particle.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I can understand this on my own since this is the defintion of the derivative. I cannot understand however why we defined the potential in that way

Comment: The term chemical "potential" is traditional, but I assume the concept is different from the electrostatic "potential" in electromagnetism. My anecdotal understanding is that $\mu$ is a coefficient, but not a potential.

Answer (score 0):

[Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) is a [thermodynamic state function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function), whose differential can be written as
$$
dG = -SdT + VdP + \mu dN,
$$
hence, by definition, $\mu$ is a partial derivative of $G$ in respect to the particle number:
$$
\mu=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N}\right)_{T, P}.
$$

See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565329/247642) regarding differentials and derivatives.